# OCaml typing error

Tags: set, logic, ocaml, formulas

Here's the type I have created to manipulate propositional formulas:

```
 type bexp = V of string
            |B of bool
            | Neg of bexp
            | And of bexp * bexp 
            | Or of bexp * bexp
            | Impl of bexp * bexp
            | Eqv of bexp * bexp
```

I need to manipulate a set of  formulas but I get error of type when I try to create it:

```
module MyOwn = struct
    type =bexp 
  compare=compare
    end ;;
      Characters 30-31:
     type =bexp
```

What did I got wrong, Can you help me,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say

```
type t = bexp
```

You just left out the type name `t`.

Comment: Thanks!Sorry to bother you beacause of my blindness! I'm a beginner in OCaml and I have a really bad time in translating pseudocode to OCaml.